# Генерация pdf из html библиотекой mpdf или dompdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf, dompdf

Сверстал html файл документа, который должен конвертироваться в pdf, и отправляться на почту, проблема в том, что при генерации, он генерируется не совсем корректно, делает большое расстояние между строками, и переносит на новую строку там, где не надо. Кто может помочь разобраться? mpdf делает это хотябы адекватней dompdf, с ним вообще беда. В приложении как должно быть, и что получается.[image: что получается]

[image: Что должно быть, просто открытый html]

Comment: В Вашем случае, скорее всего проблема заключается в ширине страницы. Выложите пример файла для конвертации, чтобы можно было составить адекватный пример в соответствии с Вашими данными.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/E5JjQE6lPuhmdw тут данная страница. Прошу пожалуйста заметить, что расстояние между строками так же большое. А когда открываю html страницу, и нажимаю печать(средствами браузера, все идеально)

Comment: wkhtmltopdf делает корректные отступы, однако почему то делает нечитабельный фон.

Comment: Уже многие библиотеки проверял. Корректнее всего было у mPDF, ну и работать мне бы с ними удобно было. Скрипт у меня под Dompdf однако они в функциях практически идентичны, но с ним так же, целая куча проблем, и все некоректно отображает.

Comment: оффтоп, конечно, но `выполнеННых`, `каРтриджа`, `полностьЮ`, `прЕтензий`

Comment: стили мешаются ваши с дефолтными небось. пропишите в заголовках явно все паддинги, марджины, в т.ч. .cell-spacing  и cell-padding для таблицы.

Comment: Дефолтные отключал вообще. Не в этом дело, гляньте шапку, поймете в чем. Верстал и заполнял не я)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте исправить css [mpdf-css](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html)

mpdf использует свои стили и классы, а не те что вы прописали в html

также можно изменить ориентацию страницы pdf(верт или горизонт) [mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/configuration/configuration-v7-x.html)

Comment: Уже пытался. Результат не меняется. Стили все-таки считываеются при генерации, это можно заметить по полосе, и многому другому. Не может ли это быть из-за шрифта? Не понял как в mdpf установить Roboto, но при использовании того, что уже имеется в mPDF, картина не меняется.

Comment: [https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html Может это поможет

Comment: Видел данную информацию, однако так и не понял как мне добавить шрифт. Да и если грешить на него, ведь в html, указывая стандартный шрифт, все нормально с отступами

Comment: Example #3 - Defining new margins and page orientation https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpage.html  Можно добавить margin для страницы `$mpdf->AddPage('L','','','','',50,50,50,50,10,10);`

Comment: Дело не в отступах, гляньте на шапку в pdf и в html, поймете